# Function not defined error for a function that's defined inside an angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

I've looked through other "function is not defined" questions, but can't seem to find one that's applicable to my use case. I'm using angular.js.

I have an initially empty div, #mylist that I am populating dynamically in the js. I have a function defined inside a controller that I'm assigning to `onChange` event of a checkbox.

Here is the full doc:

```
<!doctype html>
<html data-ng-app="testapp">
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module("testapp", []);        
        app.controller("MyAppController", function ($scope) {
            createCheckbox();

            function doSomething() {
                alert("hello!");
            }

            function createCheckbox() {
                $("#mylist").html("<input type='checkbox' onChange='javascript:doSomething();' />");
            }       
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body data-ng-controller="MyAppController">
    <div id="mylist"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When run, clicking on the checkbox results in the function not defined error.

What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: I think some paraphrasing of "You're doing it wrong" is the most common thing said around angular discussions (and it's normally true).  So basically you shouldn't be using jQuery to grab an element in the DOM... one sec think I can answer pretty easily.

Comment: For the time being, I'm employing angular just for routing. It's obvious I'm not an advanced js developer, and I couldn't tell whether the mistake was with angular or jq or plain js. I think it's reasonable to ask for help at this point to lead me in a direction.

Comment: @Steven I didn't mean to be demeaning/rude, was just saying I've heard something of that nature uttered a lot recently, that and the phrase "the angular way" which makes it sound like a cult.  I'm no JS expert either, but skipped right from AS3/Flex to AngularJS.  jQuery has always seemed a bit of a mess to me (not that Angular is all lollipops, but it feels more organized and far less error prone).  Anyhow hope my answer makes some sense, basically I'm using binding to trigger a function that is watching that variable, so when it changes I'm triggering a function.

Comment: @shaunhusain, sorry, should have directed my comment specifically. I wasn't responding to you, I was responding to Chandermani. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html data-ng-app="testapp">
<head>
    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>

var app = angular.module("testapp", []);

app.controller("MyAppController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.someProperty = true;


    $scope.$watch("someProperty", function (someProperty){
       alert("hello!"+someProperty)
     });
});

    </script>
</head>
<body data-ng-controller="MyAppController">
    <div id="mylist"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="someProperty"/></div>
</body>

</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y6XhY/

Comment: Thank you for putting together a working sample. I'll take a look through this.

Comment: oh also in this case (with a checkbox) you could just use ng-click to call a function within the scope from the HTML like ng-click="doSomething()" (or for a checkbox I believe ng-change="doSomething()") I was showing the watching a property version thinking of a input type "text" initially.

Answer (score 0):

If you use AngularJs, it's good practice to defined function inside you controller scope.$scope's field can be your function and instead of **onChange** you can use **ngChange** directive (only you have to set ngModel on that input).

```
$scope.doSomething = function() {
    alert("hello!");
}
```